# Universal app: only build classic toolkit

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I have to create a universal app from scratch. First the classic app, and at some point in the future, the modern app. I have generated the app using Cmd.

I have implemented the basics I need for the classic app, split off everything that can be reused in the modern app and put it into the shared directory. The problem is that now, when I compile with Cmd, I get the error that dependencies are missing (because views are missing in the modern app that I have implemented for classic only, but are required in shared code).

The classic app compiles find, but modern doesn't, and if there are ever errors in the classic app build process, no one will notice, because modern throws errors.

Can I tell Cmd on the command line to only compile the classic toolkit?

Comment: Did you tried this command. `sencha app build -c classic`

Comment: @UDID Nope, didn't find it in the docs. Will try, first thing monday morning.

Comment: @UDID works. Will you make that an answer, so I can accept?

Comment: @UDID doesn't work in Sencha Cmd 6.2.1 anymore, btw. "[ERR] Duplicate matches for "c" - could be: configuration cwd".

Comment: I test this in sencha Cmd 6.2.0.103 and it is fine for me. I can upgrade sencha for few days so I am not actually sure about CMD 6.2.1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In ExtJS 6 we can generate app for classic and modern separately in a similar fashion we can can build app separately for classic and modern.

you can build like this.

`sencha app build -c classic`.

Answer (score 3):

Edit the `app.json` file, and remove the section about the `modern` toolkit in the `builds` profile section; you can re-instate it when you're ready to build the `modern` part again.